# How to prove a set is compact?

Tags: general-topology

> Let A={x$\in$$\mathbb{R}^3$ : -3$\leq$$x_1^3$+$x_2$+$x_3$$\leq$3}. Is A compact
>   or not? Prove.

**What I have tried:**

I think proving that directly from the definition of compactness would be much more abstract than proving that A is closed and bounded.

Let's prove A is closed by showing that its complement {x$\in$$\mathbb{R}^3$ : $x_1$$^3$+$x_2$+$x_3$$>$3}$\cup${x$\in$$R^3$ : $x_1^3$+$x_2$+$x_3$<-3} is open. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1,x_2,x_3$)=$x_1^3$+$x_2$+$x_3$. Now we notice that

$f^{-1}$(]3,$\infty$[)={x$\in$$\mathbb{R}^3$ : $x_1$$^3$+$x_2$+$x_3$$>$3}

and $f^{-1}$(]-$\infty$,-3[)={x$\in$$R^3$ : $x_1^3$+$x_2$+$x_3$<-3}.

Thus, the complement of A is open and therefore A is closed.

Comment: I just don't see why $A$ should be bounded: it contains vectors like $(0,a,-a)$ for arbitrary $a$.

Comment: It is not quite obvious that $A$ is bounded; it is indeed false

Comment: Allright, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is not bounded, the vectors $v_n = (\sqrt[3]n, 0, -n)$ all belong to $A$, but are not bounded.